Next.js - Async server functions and re-rendering of client components
I'm working on my first Next.js project and recently stumbled on a rendering behaviour I can't explain or find any explanations online.
In this project I use client and server components and store some of my state in the URL as query params.
In one server component the values of some query params are used to fetch data from an API async.
A link / button is used to set the URL query params.
This leads to re-render all client components a second time, after the promise is resolved, even if they aren't connected with the server component.
This may be the intended behaviour but I'm not sure.
Example (just demo code):
page.tsx (URL http://localhost:3000/another-test-page)
export default function Home({ params, searchParams }: HomeProps) {
    console.log("Render HomePage");

    return (
        <main>            
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <TestServerComponent text={searchParams["text"]} />
            </Suspense>
            <TestClientComponent text={searchParams["text"]} />
            <TestTwoClientComponent />

            <div>
                <Link href="/another-test-page?text=test">
                    Add
                </Link>
                <Link href="/another-test-page">
                    Remove
                </Link>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

TestServerComponent.tsx
export default async function TestServerComponent({text}: TestServerComponentProps){
    console.log("Render TestServerComponent");
     
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 3000);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            I am a <strong>server</strong> component<br />
            Text: {text}
        </div>
    );
}

The TestClientComponent and TestTwoClientComponent  are just client components without any logic.
export default function TestClientComponent({text}: TestClientComponentProps){
    console.log("Render TestClientComponent");    

    return (
        <div>
            I am a <strong>client</strong> component<br />    
            Text: {text}        
        </div>
    );
}

The output of the logs is as following:
Server
\\On page load
Render HomePage
Render TestServerComponent
Render TestClientComponent
Render TestTwoClientComponent
 
\\ Immediately after click on the "Add"-button which adds some query params
Render HomePage
Render TestServerComponent

Browser
\\On page load
Render TestClientComponent
Render TestTwoClientComponent 

\\ Immediately after click on the "Add"-button which adds some query params
Render TestClientComponent
Render TestTwoClientComponent 

\\ After 3 seconds -> resolve of promise
Render TestClientComponent
Render TestTwoClientComponent 

Sandbox
I know that client components are only rendered on the server on full page load. After changes to the navigation the client components are only re-rendered in the browser.
Now what I don't unterstand is, why there is a second rendering of my client components after the promise is resolved. Is this the expected behaviour or is there something wrong with my code structure?
Thanks in advance

Can you share a repo/code sandbox?

Anything that changes search params through Next directly, like the Link component or the useRouter hook will cause all children of that search param page to re-render. If you want to 'shallow route', you have to go around Next and use the window directly like window.history.replaceState(null, "", \?section=${newSection}`);`

@AhmedAbdelbaset I added a link to a code sandbox

@Andrew I'm ok with re-rendering the components once. I just don't get it why there is a second re-rendering after the 3 seconds (resolve of promise). Currently the behaviour is: Button click -> Add URL query params -> re-render of client components -> after 3 seconds resolve of promise -> re-render of client components again

I really think that's just the nature of RSC's. The only way I can think of that might get around rendering twice, is to wrap it in a <Suspense> component or use Next's dynamic import which does the suspense handling for you. You can also try running it in production after building to see if things change, because React render's things twice quite often when running in strict mode in development.

Thanks @Andrew. If it's just how RSC works, I'm ok with that. I was just curious if I made a mistake somewhere and could possible improve my code. I will give it a shot to run it in production.
